# Export ContainerObject[ ] to PDF and Excel

Tags: c#, arrays, class, dataset, pdf-generation

I have no idea where to start with this, but i am trying to fill a class container which is an array, something like this:

```
public class SubContainer
{
    public string param1;
    public string param2;
    public string[] paramN;
}

public class MainContainer
{
    public string param1;
    public SubContainer;
}

public MainContainer[] FinalContainer;
```

Now i fill this container manually with a few data sets giving the needed data, but i need to grab this container filled with data and place it into a PDF file to export it to my drive.

Any suggestions or advise i should follow?

Comment: *place it into a PDF file* - how? Do you want to draw the strings on some page? Out do you want to add them in amerely machine readable way?

Comment: That container has the result of a query for a report, simple mortals should be able to read the information in a PDF or an Excel file ... I just cant find a way to migrate it to both files.

Comment: *I just cant find a way to migrate it to both files.* - do you want the PDF and Excel representations look identical? If not, consider the migrations as different tasks.

Comment: I do not really need them to look the same, i just want to migrate the data from the array object to a PDF file and an Excel file, not needed too look the same.

Comment: Ok, so they don'need to look the same. In that case you should choose one format to implement first. Choose a library / API to allowing to generate files of that kind (for Excel probably Office interop, for PDF a general purpose PDF library) and study the samples for that library / API; then start to implement. Obviously you need to know from your assignment how the data you get is formatted and how the output is expected to look like, at least in general.

Comment: The class im using has some sub classes which i fill with data from a query in a stored procedure, i know how the data output is displayed in at JSON or an XML format, but i want to translate that to export it to a PDF file ... Since its not composed of simple rows of data, each row may or may not have sub rows in a few columns, its actually hard for me to picture how the data output should be displayed on the PDF file. Also i dont know if there is a way to grab my custom class, parse it too an XML and save it in an var object and then export it to a PDF

Comment: *its actually hard for me to picture how the data output should be displayed on the PDF file.* - that should be outlined in the requirements given to you too start with.

Comment: Yeah, i was trying to ask around with the people who needs the reports, to see if they had any clue how the info should look like, but they dont help at all, so im now trying to do all this from Crystal Reports, But hey, thanks for the help and concern :)